# TypeScript Callback is undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, phaser-framework

I am trying to pass my callback `collectStar` to the `overlap` method. However, it is getting passed as `undefined`, and I don't know why.

If I pass `() => {}` instead of the reference it works; this however isn't what I want because it isn't reusable.

Here is the basics of what I am doing:

```
class SimpleGame {
    // Init the game
    constructor(width: number, height: number) {
        this.game = new Game(width, height, Phaser.AUTO, 'content', { preload: this.preload, create: this.create, update: this.update })
    }

    // Callback
    collectStar(player: Rope, star: Rope) {
        star.kill()
    }

    // The update loop
    update(){
        this.game.physics.arcade.overlap(
            this.player, 
            this.stars, 
            this.collectStar, 
            undefined, 
            this
        );
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
    new SimpleGame(800, 600)
})
```

Why is this getting passed as undefined?

Comment: Check `Function.prototype.bind()` or pass another anonymous arrow function: `() => this.collectStar()`

Comment: The Phaser framework invokes it somehow

Comment: I updated my comment, sorry :-)

Comment: I forgot to mention that `() => {}` works, but passing it by reference like above does not. So, if I try to bind, it says that it cannot bind to undefined

Comment: `this.collectStar.bind(this)` would totally work

Comment: That is what I thought, but its throwing an error.

Comment: "it works (this however isn't what I want)." --- then you need to explain what you want and why an arrow function is not a solution. "That is what I though, but its throwing an error" --- what error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155961/discussion-between-zerkms-and-get-off-my-lawn).

Comment: Okay, If I do `static collectStar` it works

Comment: You're working around the problem, not solving it.